# Setting up Firefox build

Tags: firefox

I am getting this error in start shell MSCV 2015

> ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the build [pre-requisites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites#Getting_The_Tools.). At this time, it means you need to have installed [Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) with C++ support. As the docs state:

> Firefox relies on C++ features that aren't supported in older versions
>   of Visual Studio. **Do not accept the default configuration.** Instead,
>   select Programming Languages > Visual C++ > Common Tools for Visual
>   C++ 2015.